# .NET - Dataset is a derivative of IEnumerable?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0, dataset, ienumerable

I've been reading up on LINQ and the Dataset classh, and my book states that the Dataset class in .NET implements or is a derivative of IEnumerable (my book is not clear of which one).

1. In the context of programming what does derivative mean?
2. I looked at the [Dataset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) class on MSDN and it gave no indication that it was a derivative of or implemented IEnumerable.  How is the Dataset class and IEnumerable related?
3. For future reference, how do I find out?  Did i miss something on MSDN?  I would think it would be documented somewhere...

Thank You

Comment: out of curiosity, which book is that?

Comment: @Marc Fravell, its the "MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-515): Web Applications Development with Microsoft .NET Framework 4"  - Quite a mouthful lol

Comment: MS Press, bless them, are sadly notorious for needing excessively large errata; I guess they are keen to get to press etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't implement `IEnumerable`, but it does implement `IListSource`. `IListSource` has a method `GetList()` which returns an `IList` which implements `IEnumerable`.

What it means that it implements `IEnumerable` (or, you can get an `IEnumerable` as is the case here) is that you can use the following construct:

```
foreach (var item in dataSet.GetList())
{
    // Do something with item
}
```

It's an easy way to walk over all items of a set ("enumerate" the items).

How do you find out whether you can do this? Most of the times, it's obvious. Everything that contains a set of items should probably implement `IEnumerable`. Over time, you get a feel for this.

Answer (score 3):

A "derivative" *might* mean "inherits from" or "subclasses", but either way that terminology would be wrong; `IEnumerable[<T>]` is an interface, so a type might **implement** this interface.

Equally, the book is wrong - it doesn't:

```
public class DataSet : MarshalByValueComponent, IListSource, IXmlSerializable,
     ISupportInitializeNotification, ISupportInitialize, ISerializable
```

The `.Tables` are enumerable, however; [`DataTableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablecollection.aspx) gets that from [it's base-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase.aspx):

```
public class InternalDataCollectionBase : ICollection, IEnumerable
```

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) is indeed your friend, or just "show definition" in visual studio.